# CD/DVD image mounting on Windows 98

Tags: windows, mount, compact-disc

Which software (and which version) can i install on old computer with Windows 98? All i can find is designed to xp and newer systems and dint even installs on 98.

I made old computer to play old games, most of them i have in iso's files (backup made some time ago) - original CDs are now very damaged, real cd-rom drive can not read any of them properly.

Comment: This isn't quite what you're asking for, but if you have another computer running a newer version of Windows, you can mount the image on that and share the virtual drive. Then your Win98 computer should be able to read it over the network and install the games that way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Slysoft Virtual Clone Drive? http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html

System Requirements
An IBM-compatible personal computer with a minimum 500 MHz Pentium-class microprocessor (1 GHz recommended) and 128 MB RAM (256 MB recommended)

**Windows 98**, Windows ME, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7 (32 or 64 bit)

It states that it works from Windows 98 all up to Windows 7. Might be worth a try